# PhpStorm - Show Project Files and Structure at the same time

Tags: phpstorm

They seemed to have changed the default at some point.
Previously I had in my left tree view the top half with the project files and the bottom half with the Structure of the specific file, now I only have one or the other.

There is no doubt a setting to get it back, but the settings are more than slightly obscure.

Can someone please give me a hint of how to get this back?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you have there right now and how you wish it to be. Do you want to see them (Project View panel and Structure panel) on different sides of the screen ... or on the same side (one above and second below). This all can be configured via right click menu on corresponding panel header or even by drag-and-drop. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tool-windows.html

Comment: Just drug a corresponding tool window button down: https://i.gyazo.com/044a5e56b8a0b24aa4619a2a9f929f42.mp4

Comment: Perfect the mp4 helped do what I wanted, had dragged it all over the place but obviously not in the correct place.